# ECW Support in GeoServer 2.12.1?

Tags: geoserver, gdal, ecw

I am trying to add ECW support into GeoServer 2.12.1 but no luck so far.

Does anyone have a step by step guide to add the ECW support?

Answer (score 3):

Step-by-step instructions for installing ECW support are provided in the GeoServer manual, as part of the [GDAL Image Formats](http://docs.geoserver.org/maintain/en/user/data/raster/gdal.html) section.

I'm not sure if its a problem in your case, but for some reason people miss the part that says:

> Moreover, in order for GeoServer to leverage these libraries, the GDAL
>   (binary) libraries must be installed through your host system’s OS.
>   Once they are installed, GeoServer will be able to recognize GDAL data
>   types. See below for more information.

Also note that the ECW licensing contains some non-standard conditions, which you should evaluate for your specific needs and situation, or seek legal advice to interpret if needed.

Comment: Thanks BradHards, I have ECW image, that image need to show in GeoServer.

Comment: In which OS were you trying to install ECW extension in geoserver?

Comment: As suggested by @BradHards did you try this http://docs.geoserver.org/maintain/en/user/data/raster/gdal.html ?

Comment: You may get it to work but by the ECW SDK license it is not allowed to use the SDK on server applications without having a license from Hexagon https://www.hexagongeospatial.com/. Convert you images to tiled, JPEG compressed GeoTIFF files if you do not want to pay.